# Applying custom image to an existing azure scaleset which was created using custom image

Tags: azure-devops, azure-vm-scale-set

I have created an azure scaleset using custom image. when I try to upgrade the scale set with another custom image using "Azure VMSS: update with immutable machine image" I get the following error

> Failed to update image for VMSS testvmssapp. Error: VMSS testvmssapp
>   can not be updated as it uses a platform image. Only a VMSS which is
>   currently using a custom image can be updated.

Is there something I am missing with custom scaleset image?

```
"storageProfile": {
            "osDisk": {
              "createOption": "FromImage",
              "caching": "ReadWrite",
              "managedDisk": {
                "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS"
              },
              "diskSizeGB": 127
            },
            "imageReference": {
              "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/testvmssdeployment/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/MyCustomImage"
            }
          },
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I will try over the weekend and let you know

Comment: How did it go, Any good news?

Comment: Yes the below one does work. but it looks like the Azure Devops "Build immutable machine image" task is outdated and cannot be used when using the defaults packer template =  auto generated it does not have setting "managed_image_name": "myPackerImage" hence it does not created managed image but vhd in storage The output of this task is a url to the vhd. Also the task " Azure VMSS: update with immutable machine image" is outdated it only access .vhd image url and no managed image

Comment: If "Build immutable machine image" task got an issue , you can report it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues).

Answer (score 1):

I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11684) about task **Azure VM scale set deployment** that you track on.

As workaround, You can try updating the image by using azure powershell task or azure cli task in your pipeline to run below script.

Azure Powershell:

```
Update-AzVmss `
    -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" `
    -VMScaleSetName "myScaleSet" `
    -ImageReferenceId /subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/myNewImage
```

Azure CLI:

```
az vmss update \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name myScaleSet \
    --set virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.id=/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/myNewImage
```

Another workaround to this issue is to create a VHD file, and use this VHD file to create the VSS using this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-windows-customimage/scripts). And then you will have a Image resource that has a URL which you can use for task Azure VM scale set deployment. Please check [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/299923/creating-cd-with-tfs-to-azure-scale-set.html) for information

Answer (score 0):

From [OS Updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#os-updates) for a scale set, If you use Azure **platform images**, you can update the image by modifying the `imageReference`. With platform images, it is common to specify "latest" for the image reference version. If you use **custom images**, you can update the image by updating the `imageReference` ID.

Since you have created a scale set with a base image windows-2012-R2-datacenter. It's deployed from [platform Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-automatic-upgrade#supported-os-images). It's not supported by changing the image from platform to custom. For more information, please read [here1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/16899) and [here2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/352d03c3-52d9-4fa8-a370-270731889fab/auto-scale-set-change-image-operationnotallowed?forum=AzureStack).

In this case, you could directly recreate a scale set with a new custom Image or remove the old scale set. This is [the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachinescalesets/createorupdate#create-a-scale-set-from-a-custom-image.) for creating a scale set from a custom image.