# Updating virtual machine scale set with a new image

Tags: azure, devops

I have been working on it straight for the past 2 days and read all the possible documentation that i can find.

I have a scaleset (windows machines that will hold an asp.net core app on it). Here's what the setup looks like.

1. I have a "Pipeline" that gets the code and publishes the artifact (this is working as expected)
2. Now I am trying to use that artifact and build a new image and push it to the scaleset.

Here are the screenshots of what the release pipeline looks like.
[pipeline tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkHPt.png)
[scaleset release error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QxsM.png)

So the first step builds an image using packer and the second step is supposed to push that image to the scale sets.

The error basically states "Error: VMSS myapp can not be updated as it uses a platform image. Only a VMSS which is currently using a custom image can be updated."

I have tried this release pipeline with 2 different scalesets. One of them was using default windows 2016 image and the other one was using a custom image that was built. In both the cases I run into the same error.

I have spent a LOT of hours trying to figure this out to no avail. I have also asked around in all the communities that i am a part of. Is anyone out there aware of how to update these damnned scale sets with a new image of your application?

Comment: You issue looks similar to [https://stackoverflow.com/q/58658792/5344880] question. Please see if it helps.